# Error registering a task for sensor tracking with expo-background-fetch and expo-task-manager in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, sensors, background-task

I am working on a sensor tracking feature in a React Native application. At first I was running it in foreground and that is working perfectly but I want to track also during screen lock, Hence, I am using now expo-background-fetch, expo-task-manager, and expo-sensors. I have created a custom hook to manage the sensor tracking task, but I keep encountering an error that the task is not defined whenever I try to register it. Interestingly, a similar approach works fine for location tracking in my app. Below is the simplified code for my custom component and hook:

**Component**

```js
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";
import { useSensorTracking } from "./useSensorTracking";

function SensorTrackingComponent() {
  const updateTimeInterval = 1000;
  const acceleration = useSelector((state) => state.trackingData.acceleration);

  useSensorTracking(updateTimeInterval);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Acceleration: {acceleration}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SensorTrackingComponent />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**Hook**

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import { Accelerometer } from 'expo-sensors';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setAcceleration } from './trackingDataSlice';

// Simplified to handle only acceleration for demonstration purposes
export function useSensorTracking(updateTimeInterval: number) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const taskName = 'acceleration-tracking-task';

    const handleSensorData = useCallback(async (measurement) => {
        // do other stuff
        dispatch(setAcceleration(measurement));
    }, [dispatch]);

    const startSensorTracking = useCallback(async () => {
        await Accelerometer.requestPermissionsAsync();
        Accelerometer.setUpdateInterval(updateTimeInterval);
        Accelerometer.addListener(handleSensorData);
    }, [updateTimeInterval, handleSensorData]);

    const stopSensorTracking = useCallback(() => {
        Accelerometer.removeAllListeners();
    }, []);

    const defineTask = useCallback(() => {
        TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, async () => {
            await startSensorTracking();
            return BackgroundFetch.Result.NoData;
        });
    }, [startSensorTracking]);

    useEffect(defineTask, [updateTimeInterval]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const registerBackgroundFetchAsync = async () => {
        if (!TaskManager.isTaskDefined(taskName)) {
          defineTask();
        }
        return await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName, {
          minimumInterval: 60,
          stopOnTerminate: true,
          startOnBoot: false,
        });
      };

      const unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync = async () => {
        return await BackgroundFetch.unregisterTaskAsync(taskName);
      };

      registerBackgroundFetchAsync();

      return () => {
        stopSensorTracking();
        unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync();
      };
    }, [updateTimeInterval]);
}
```

I have defined and registered the background fetch task within the useSensorTracking hook. However, when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```bash
Error: Task 'acceleration-tracking-task' is not defined. You must define a task using TaskManager.defineTask before registering.
```

I'm calling TaskManager.defineTask and BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync as per the documentation, but still facing this issue. Thus, I have changed and combined the `useEffect` calls but without any positive effect. Moving it out to top-level is unfortunately not an option due to the use of some state values.

I am aware of defining the task at top-level but I have the constraint that I need runtime data in my background task and this approach works perfectly with location tracking elsewhere in my app, so I'm puzzled as to why it's not working here. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or how to debug this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The function  ```registerBackgroundFetchAsync();``` is async but called like an sync method, try to call  registerBackgroundFetchAsync(); like ```await registerBackgroundFetchAsync();```

Comment: @michaelBahl thanks and you are right about the async nature of the function but I just thought that the callback in the `useEffect` has to be a sync function in order to work